# R - How to create a vector with propagated dates

Tags: r, date, for-loop, vector

I am trying to create a vector (*dateVec*) which contains the dates in the column *Date* propagated by the number of days in column *Days*. I cannot understand why the code that I created is not working. Dates are in Date format.

```
> for ( i in mydata[,1] ) {
>       dateVec = mydata [,1] + 0 : mydata [,2] }
```

The data has much more rows, here is a sample as an example:

```
Date (mydata[,1]) -- Days (mydata[,2])

10/05/2017 ----------       3

05/05/2017  ----------      2
```

The result that I would expect for *dateVec* would be:

```
(10/05/2017, 11/05/2017, 12/05/2017, 13/05/2017, 05/05/2017, 06/05/2017, 07/05/2017, ...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here why your code isn't working.

1. For loop: Here, your i needs a series of integers to iterate through. As you
   have it now, you are trying to loop from i = 1 to "10/05/2017" and "05/05/2017".
   A more useful way is to use seq_along to generate a sequence of integers from 
   1 to the length of the object passed through to seq_along.
2. dateVec is not indexed, so that you are overwriting dateVec for each
   iteration of your loop
3. Variable length of days. For the first date, you are generating a sequence 3
   days long and for the second date, 2 days. You will need a data structure that can handle variable length element such as a list.

To modify your existing code:

```
    mydata <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("10/05/2017", "05/05/2017"),
                         format = "%d/%m/%Y"), Days = c(3, 2))
    dateVec <- list()

    for (i in seq_along(mydata[, 1])) {
       dateVec[[i]] = mydata [i, 1] + 0 : mydata [i, 2]
     }

    res <- do.call("c", dateVec)
```

A more r idiomatic approach is to pass the starting date and length of time in parallel using mapply to return a list, which is then concatenated to a vector of dates

```
res <- do.call("c", mapply(function(x, y) seq(from = x, length.out = y,
     by = "1 day"), x = mydata[["Date"]], y = mydata[["Days"]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clunky solution:

```
library("lubridate")
mydata = data.frame(Date = dmy(c("10/05/2017", "05/05/2017")),
                    Days = c(3,2))
dateVec = dmy(character())

for(i in 1:length(mydata$Date)){
  dateVec = c(dateVec,mydata$Date[i])
  for(j in 1:mydata$Days[i]){
    dateVec = c(dateVec, mydata$Date[i]+j)
  }
}
```

Note that this uses the lubridate package and doesn't format the dates quite how you did. I also found it interesting that I had to initialize `dateVec` as a date object. Initially I tried `dateVec = c()` but R tried to coerce to numeric.